# How to add rounded border in step progress

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create a step progress bar like the one below

[image: step progress bar]

but I only find packages that do not have this option, does anyone know of a package or any way of doing this?

The closest you can get was using this lib:
step_progress_indicator 0.2.1+4

[image: my step progress bar]

```
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
           child: StepProgressIndicator(
             size: 8,
             totalSteps: 8,
             currentStep: 3,
             selectedColor: Colors.black,
             unselectedColor: Colors.grey,
             padding: 0.8,
           ),
         ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the behavior of this plugin, but maybe wrapping it in a `ClipRRect` widget can help you:

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0), // Change this like you want
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  child: StepProgressIndicator(
    size: 8,
    totalSteps: 8,
    currentStep: 3,
    selectedColor: Colors.black,
    unselectedColor: Colors.grey,
    padding: 0.8,
  ), 
),
```

Hope this will help!